# What is the meaning of $\mathbb{E}^x$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

What does $\mathbb{E}^x((X_t)_{t \in T})$ for some stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \in T}$ mean? I heard that it is some kind of conditional expectation given that $X(0)=x$, but I can't find a precise definiton. Is it the stochastic process $t\mapsto\mathbb{E}(X_t|\{X(0)=x\})$, where $0$ is the first element in $T$? If yes, is there a simpler way to rewrite this?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2179672/36150); see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3446864/36150) for some material on Brownian motion